# UISearchbar when added programmatically don`t call didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have a Table View Controller that I add programmatically the UISearchBar like this (this is on my ViewDidLoad):

```
searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 64)];
searchDisplayController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];
searchDisplayController.delegate = self;
searchDisplayController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
searchBar.delegate = self;
[self.tableView.tableHeaderView addSubview:searchBar];
[self.tableView.tableHeaderView sizeToFit];
```

I dont`t set as the tableHeaderView because I have another view on the Header (in blue).

[image: My Tableview]

The problem is when I search and click on the cell, the method didSelectRowAtIndexPath is not called. And, as it shows on my image, I need to know what cell was selected do add a check mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign 'self' as the searchResultsDelegate as well.  Like this.

```
    searchDisplayController.searchResultsDelegate = self;
```

Then in your didSelectRowForIndexPath, you will need to distinguish between the search table, and your regular table.  Like this:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ( tableView == _searchController.searchResultsTableView) {
        // user selected a row in your search results table
    } else {
        // user selected a row in your main table
    }
}
```

You will also need to make this distinction (test for searchResultsTableView) in your other delegate methods, if any, such as tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath.